# Projection Matrix or not? (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, projection

Is it necessary to use a projection matrix like so:

```
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

and

Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Calculate the projection and view transformation and store results in mMVPMatrix
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

I'm having no end of trouble doing a simple 2d (sprite) rotation around the z axis.

The most success I've had so far is to manipulate the rotation matrix (rotate and translate) and pass it directly to the vertex shader.

It's not perfect and carries with it some shearing/skewing/distortion but at least it allows me to move the 'pivot'/centre point of the quad.  If I put the above lines in the whole thing breaks and I get all kinds of odd results.

```
What is the actual purpose of the lines above (I have read the android docs but I dont understand them) and are they necessary?  Do people write OpenGl apps without them?
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Your eye position's z is 3 as is your frustrum's near plane distance. If you have your sprite's z = 0, then they end up directly on the near plane, which might cause some effects. You could try to reduce your near plane distance or move your sprites towards neg. z.

Comment: Comment when downvoting please.  This (downvoting without comment) helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a C API but many frameworks will wrap its functions into other functions to make life easier. For example, in OpenGL ES 2.0 you must create and pass matrices to OpenGL. But OpenGL does not provide you with any tools to actually build and calculate these matrixes. This is where many other libraries exist to do this matrix creation for you, and then you pass these constructed matrixes to OpenGL -- or the function may very well pass the matrix to OpenGL for you, after making the calculation. Just depends on the library.

You can easily not use these frameworks and do it yourself, which is a great way to learn the math in 3D graphics -- and the math is really key to everything in this area.

I'm sure you have direct access to the OpenGL API in Android, but you are choosing to use a library that perhaps Android provides natively (similar to how Apple provides GLKit, a recent addition to their frameworks for iOS). But that doesn't mean you *must* use that library, but it might provide faster development *if you know what the library is doing*.

In this case, the three functions above appear to be pretty generic matrix/graphics utilities. You have a frustrum function that sets the projection in 3D space. You have the lookAt function that determines what the view of the camera is -- where is it looking and where is the camera while it looks there.

And you have a matrix multiplication function, since in the end all matrices must be combined before they are applied to the vertices of your 3D object.

It's important to understand that a typical modelview matrix will include the camera orientation/location but it will also include the rotation and scaling of your object. So just sending a modelview based on the camera (from LookAt) is not enough, unless you want your object to remain at the center of the screen, with no rotation.

If you were to expand all the math that goes into matrix multiplication, it might look like this for a typical setup:

Frustum * Camera * Translation * Rotation * Vertices

Those middle three, Camera, Translation, Rotation, are usually combined together into your modelview, so multiply those together for that particular matrix, then multiply the modelview by your frustum projection matrix, and this whole result can be applied to your vertices.

You must be very careful about the order of the matrix multiplication. Multiplying a frustum by a modelview is not the same as multiplying a modelview by a frustum.

Now you mention skewing, distortion, etc. One possible reason for this is your viewport. I'm sure somewhere in your API is an option to set the viewport's height and width, which are usually the height and width of your screen. If they are set differently, you will get an improper aspect ratio and some skewing that you see. Just one possible explanation. Or it could be that your parameters to your frustum aren't quite right, since that will certainly affect things like skew also.

Comment: Hey @SebbyJohanns, thanks for the answer and for the explanation :-) do I actually need one?  The reason that I ask is that initially (without applying frustum (or orthographic projection) and camera, my coordinates went from -1 through +1 and my code worked OK, however, since I've applied them the range has changed (-1.7 through +1.7) - this is for X axis only, y seems unaffected.  So I wondered if it's normal practice to write OpenGL code without these?  Or do people always implement these?

Comment: you need to implement a frustum in 3d graphics, yes, otherwise how would you or the graphics engine know what areas of 3d space will actually appear onscreen? Perhaps the library you are using is creating a default orthographic projection for you if you don't supply a projection yourself. i highly recommend you learn some of the basics about how 3d works so you are feel more in control of the process. coding blind is not a good approach. here is a good resource: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html and http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/